# Centering a div vertically in react bootstrap

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have recently taken over the frontend of a project and I am not able to understand how to vertically center a div inside a flexbox. I tried looking at resources online but I wasn't able to understand anything that would help me.
Any help would really be appreciated

---

```
      <div className="h-[40vh] w-2/3 flex justify-around items-center border border-grey" >
        <div className="container w-1/3 h-full bg-neutral-300 p-5">
          <div>
            <h1 className="font-bold text-xl mb-3">{userDetails.name}</h1>
            <p className="text-md">Phone Number : <span>{userDetails.phone}</span></p>
            <p className="text-md">Email : <span>{userDetails.email}</span></p>
            <p className="text-md">Date and Time of last contact : </p>
            <p className="text-md">Products Interested :</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-2/3 flex justify-center">
          <h2> Conversation Summary </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

---

The current div looks something like this

[image: Current Div]

I want just the details inside the grey box to be centered vertically

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? The current one (5.1) has vertical alignment https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/vertical-align/ I don't know how different react-bootstrap is but there might be an equivalent?

Flexbox: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#align-items